# Query data from both SQL Server and Azure DocumentDB?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

We have quite a big SQL server database which keeps track of subscribers to email newsletters (currently about 100k users) and we're building something that will track data for each newsletter sent, including whether each person has bounced/received/viewed/clicked an email. So, this could result in millions of rows in the statistics tables and we were thinking of trying out Document DB for the first time.

My question is whether it's possible to query data in SQL server and Document DB at the same time. Maybe there is a way to join directly, or by using LINQ in c#. I'm no expert but I know that you can query multiple SQL server databases at the same time.

The main thing is that we need to be able to cross-reference the main Subscribers list with all the data kept in Document DB by using their unique subscriber ID.

Comment: What about setting up a linked server object in SQL Server that uses the MongoDB driver to connect to DocumentDB? I haven't tested this but seems like it should work

Comment: @GregGalloway I believe you'd have to install a MongoDB ODBC driver, which might not be possible. In any event, this is a really bad "code smell."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server and DocumentDB are completely separate engines. You'd need to build your own dual-query code in your client / app server. And how you accomplish this is completely up to you: there's no "right" way to do this.

Note: This is a common scenario of "polyglot persistence" - mixing multiple storage engines within a single app. There's no magic bullet which lets you query multiple storage systems together. You just need to deal with each storage system as needed.

This (the idea of multiple-database-system queries) would be the case with just about any two disparate database engines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can..just linked servers within SSMS. Download the ODBC drivers from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/odbc-driver.
You can also connect via Visual Studio and run queries directly there once the ODBC drivers have been set. Everything is completely SQL (No C# needed, if C#, use Linqpad)

[SSMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ct6U.png)